# Persistent typeclass instances for existing libraries ADT's

Tags: haskell, yesod, typeclass, persistent

I'm trying to insert all data in a [`Status`](https://github.com/himura/twitter-types/blob/master/twitter-types/Web/Twitter/Types.hs#L122) with Persistent. What is the easiest way for me to make `Status` (and types within it) instances of `Persistent`?

I'm going to have to create `PersistEntity` instances for each one right? Can anyone provide an example of one?

Comment: You could write all the typeclass instances by hand, but it would be simpler to use [persistent-template](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-template-2.1.3.4/docs/Database-Persist-TH.html) to derive them.

Comment: @user2407038 I still need to create an EntityDef for each type right? For instance I don't see anything that can go from MyType -> PersistEntity MyType in persist-template. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use the `persistLowerCase` quasiquoter to create the `EntityDef` for each type - the syntax of `persistLowerCase` is very similar to that of Haskell datatype declarations, so changing your code shouldn't be hard.

Comment: @user2407038 The problem is that it is a libraries code. I was looking for a way to turn the already defined Tweet type into a PersistEntity so I can use the insert function on it.